# Waiting for user events in parallel sequences and best way to progress within Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

In a few areas of a workflow I'm building, the workflow creates a "task" (or many in parallel sequences) in a SQL data layer and sends email to business users.
The email has a link to a client UI which shows the task, the user "completes" the task which then updates the task in SQL data layer. 
The workflow currently is in a while loop in each sequence instance with a delay checking for the task to complete. 
I would like to adjust this to a Receive Activity, as I will have many workflow instances running. 
Is there a suitable approach to this and maybe some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Receive would work, but if you just want to implement an event-driven workflow, look into the Pick activity:

Pick activity overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358746.aspx
Pick activity sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807389.aspx